# Value of integral greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: definite-integrals, approximate-integration

Is there an elementary way to prove that
$$\int\limits_{-1}^1 \frac{\arccos x}{\exp(x)+1}>\frac{\pi}{2} ~~?$$
The approximate value of the integral is 1.75.

I have tried to restrict to a smaller interval and to take minimum values of $\arccos$ on that interval.

Comment: I've tried the same; I get $\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{\arccos x}{e^x + 1} > \frac{\pi - 1}{2}$

Comment: I can't quite get the needed bound on the upper half; the area is 1 for the numerator alone, and dividing by 1+e makes it too small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By even/odd symmetry we have that

$$I \equiv \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\arccos x}{e^x+1}dx = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\pi - \arccos x}{e^{-x}+1}dx$$

$$\implies I = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}dx + \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \arccos x\cdot\frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{2+e^{-x}+e^x}dx$$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin x\right)\frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{2+e^{-x}+e^x}dx $$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{2}+\int_{0}^1 \arcsin x\cdot\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2+e^{-x}+e^x}dx$$

The integrand on the right is strictly positive, thus we have $I > \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: (+1) This is the way I was proceeding.

Comment: @JohnnyC it's not forgotten, the integral evaluates to $1$

Comment: @NinadMunshi: You're right/my bad.